# strange behaviour in StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync

Tags: c#, .net, windows, async-await

I'm doing something for a windows store app, it's an Universal App project and I'm debugging on a Windows 8.1 notebook and a windows 8.1 Surface Pro 3.

I'm trying to create some nested folders in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. 
From the constructor of the main screen, I call

```
CacheManager.InitializeOfflineFiles().Wait();
```

and the code for CacheManager.InitializeOfflineFiles() is

```
public static async Task InitializeOfflineFiles()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder s1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("one", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        Debug.WriteLine("Created folder one");
        StorageFolder s2 = await s1.CreateFolderAsync("two", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        Debug.WriteLine("Created folder two");
        StorageFolder s3 = await s2.CreateFolderAsync("three", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        Debug.WriteLine("Created folder three");
        StorageFolder s4 = await s3.CreateFolderAsync("four", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        Debug.WriteLine("Created folder four");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Windows doesn't love you. Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

When I debug this, it doesn't get past creating folder "two". No exception logged, no nothing. Also, when I run this without debugging (Ctrl + F5), same result, only dir "one/two" gets created in the local storage.

Is this a case of misunderstanding  async programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
CacheManager.InitializeOfflineFiles().Wait();
```

Is causing your app to **deadlock**. This is why you're seeing the "hanging" behavior. It is peculiar that you seem to be seeing folder 1 & 2 being created, as i assume this should deadlock when the first `await` is executed.

This is the reason you [shouldn't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Since constructors can't be async, use the "Initialize Pattern" ([or other known async initalization patterns](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)) instead to execute your async code:

```
public Task InitializeAsync()
{
    return InitializeOfflineFilesAsync()
}
```

And from your code, call this from an `async` context method, perhaps an *event handler*:

```
public async void SomeButtonClickEventHandler()
{
    await InitializeAsync();
}
```

The moral of the story is, don't call asynchronous methods via your constructor.

Comment: I thought about this, but then, why doesn't it deadlock on the first `CreateFolderAsync` calls, but only on the third?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I know, it's weird. We're definitely missing some data. I don't see any other reason why this should hang, but i can't explain the hanging only after the second `await`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I admit I don't know anything about this windows API, which is obvious from my noob question, but it's really frustrating to get a deadlock this way. In Java you have to work hard for a deadlock, here the OS does this for you. I really wanted to have a synchronous initialization block, but they do not provide any sync methods for storage. This is really stupid.

Comment: @VictorIonescu I understand your frustration. This happens *alot*. I answer a couple of questions like these couple times a week. It happens because the `async-await` and asynchronous API's are more complex than people think.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that i can call the async method from the constructor. 
In the constructor:

```
 var task = Task.Run(async () =>
   {
       return await CacheManagerInitializeOfflineFiles();
   });
   string dummy = task.Result;
```

The method in same class calling the async method that creates storage dirs:

```
private async Task<string> CacheManagerInitializeOfflineFiles()
{
    await CacheManager.InitializeOfflineFiles();
    return "done";
}
```

I really don't want to put a button "initialize application", that would be bad design :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid deadlock, try this:

```
StorageFolder s1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("one", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
```